# Which folder to put 9png images to?

Tags: android, android-layout, nine-patch

We use 9png mainly to reduce the size of the apk. But, I am facing a peculiar problem. I am not sure in which folder I have to place the 9pngs in. I had put them in HDPI folder. Since Android is 'clever' it looks like if I use the app in an MDPI phone, it 'scales' the 9png which creates crazy effects. I didn't face any major problem until I tried it in Galaxy note. Looks like the 9png was taken from HDPI and scaled (Note has 800x1280) and it created weird effects.

- So which is the right place to put the 9pngs?
- How to tell Android system not to 'scale' 9pngs based on the folder it is put in?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

According to Romain Guy's [answer](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/8d9413d1b2012b7d?pli=1) on Google groups:

> The behavior of 9-patch is undefined when shrunk. In practice you will
>   see  overlaps of the various sections of the 9patch. Don't do it :)

From what I noticed in my projects, a 9PNG is scaled down just like any regular PNG, so I am usually requesting to our designer the entire set of images for `ldpi, mdpi, hdpi` and `xhdpi`, and I transform them all in 9patches.

That, unless there is a very simple 9patch, like a plain button background, that makes no difference when stretched or shrunk, so I usually place it in the regular `drawable` folder.

Answer (score 11):

I had a similar problem with a nine patch image: if I placed it in the `res/drawable` folder, it didn't work on an `ldpi` screen (it distorted the image and lost the transparency).

The solution for me was to put it in the `res/drawable-nodpi` folder. The documentation states:

> This can be used for bitmap resources that you do not want to be
>   scaled to match the device density.

Comment: This works for assets that don't contain any density-dependent features such as rounded corners.

Answer (score 0):

Just put the 9png in your HDPI folder.

if the effect looks weird in your Galaxy Note.

Ask the designer to give you a new 9png file for the XHDPI. and then put the new file in folder XHDPI.